# Why is input box on same lines?

Tags: html, css, input

I Have been learning HTML and CSS for 2 days now so the code is probably sloppy but does anyone know why the input boxes aren’t on separate lines even though they are in different div elements.

I have a different code where they are in separate lines and almost copied it to a T but the problem is still occurring. The first text is my HTML and my second text is the CSS. The image is the output, also this is my first post so sorry if I did anything wrong

**outcome**:

[image]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, purple, rgb(0, 183, 255));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.glass{
    height: 550px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid;
    background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38,1);
    border-radius: 10%;
    box-shadow: 10px 45px 100px black;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}

input{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="glass"></div>

    <form action="results.html" method="GET">

        <div class="email">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="pass">
            <label for="password"></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its because form is display: flex. Those divs will lose their 'block level' statues and will display in a row format.  (Side note: Unrelated, remove position: absolute, as I imagine you didn't mean to use this)

Comment: OK to learn but IMHO gray text on darker gray makes my eyes look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Flex defaults to direction `row`, you'll need `flex-direction: column` to make them on 2 lines.

Also, the `transform: scale(1.5,1.5)` on the `form` causes the element to grow over his parent.

If you're trying to enlarge the text, use `font-size`, `scale` is not needed here.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, purple, rgb(0, 183, 255));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.glass{
    height: 550px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid;
    background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38,1);
    border-radius: 10%;
    box-shadow: 10px 45px 100px black;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    /* transform: scale(1.5,1.5); */
}

input{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="glass"></div>

    <form action="results.html" method="GET">

        <div class="email">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="pass">
            <label for="password"></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Heyy..you just used display flex in form tag which overrides the property of div inside form from block to inline..i had fixed it for you..
```

```css
 *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, purple, rgb(0, 183, 255));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.glass{
    height: 550px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid;
    background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38,1);
    border-radius: 10%;
    box-shadow: 10px 45px 100px black;
}

form{
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}

input{
    border: none;
    background: white;
    margin-top:10px;

}
.label{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="glass"></div>

    <form action="results.html" method="GET">

        <div class="email">
            <label for="email" class="label">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="pass">
            <label for="password" class="label">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```